# Access to the path is denied VS 2017 Unable to copy file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, access-denied

Been having the weirdest problem with Visual Studio lately. I'm running 2017 and I have a repo I have been collaborating on with a co-worker for a while when all of a sudden the other day I tried to build and I got a couple of errors that read,

> Access to the path function.json is denied

and then after a few more attempts at building and cleaning the solution, I get a ton of MSB3021 errors stating,

> Unable to copy file "localfilepath.dll" to "bin\Debug...\file.dll"

I have a coworker who is able to access the repo just fine on his machine and everything builds normally. Unsure if it is related but this is a project with 2 Azure function projects and 1 class library project. The rest of my local repos work just fine building and rebuilding too.

**What I've tried:**

- Closing all instances of Visual Studio and reopening the project (Nothing changes)
- Restarting my computer (I can build successfully the first time I open the project but never the second time. That's when I get all the errors back again)
- Deleting the repo locally from my machine and pulling down a fresh copy from github (Exact same issues reproduce)

Comment: It sounds as if your application is still running after your first build. Check browser windows or maybe IIS (express) to see if it still has a running application.

Comment: @oerkelens I did actually wonder if this might be happening too but when I checked IIS wasn't running

Comment: When you try to build, which button are you hitting?  Build, IIS Express (run), or a publish?

Comment: @nurdyguy Build. But I've tried all the alternatives as well with the same results.

Comment: If you restart your box, build once (successfully), and then try to build again, it fails?  Even though you did nothing between the builds?  What about build-clean-build?

Comment: @nurdyguy Yes secondary builds fail even though nothing happenned between builds and the same thing happens for a build-clean-build

Comment: Well, it really feels like an IIS issue but that doesn't explain why it fails even if you didn't attach to IIS.  When you do run, do you usually attach to local host (IIS Express) or attach to IIS pool?

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: @nurdyguy Yes I am running as administrator. Was hoping that might be a fix too. Something wonky is going on with processes. When I start my computer up fresh I can delete bin folders but after I load up and try to build once I no longer have access to delete them even though I am the administrator. Even after closing visual studio I can't until I restart my computer again.

Comment: IIS does sometimes cause this kind of thing, hanging on to a file in the deployment even after the process is ended.  Sorry, that's all I can think of.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem? I'm also experiencing the same behavior -  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug..." to "bin\Debug...". Access to path "bin\Debug\net47\..." is denied. First reboot allows a build, second builds fail - every time!

Comment: @pieperu If I remember right I got a new computer the next week and had to resetup everything from the repo and it worked fine. My guess is wiping out your file structure and pulling it back down from your repo might be another option to see if that refreshes things.

Comment: Do you put your project in dropbox folder or any other auto sync folder?

Answer (score 1):

## How to Solve the Issue

One of the easiest ways to handle locked files or folders is to use Microsoft Sysinternals [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Using Process Explorer there is a simple way to find what program is using a file.

Open Process Explorer

Running as administrator.

On the toolbar, find the "gunsight" icon on the right.

Drag the icon and drop it on the open file or folder that is locked.

The executable that is using the file will be highlighted in the Process Explorer main display list.

---

**OR**

Open Process Explorer running as administrator.

Enter the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+F or, click the “Find” menu and select “Find a Handle or DLL” and a search dialog box will open.

Type in the name of the locked file or other file of interest.

> function.json

Partial names are usually sufficient.

Click the button “Search” and list will be generated, there may be a number of entries.

---

To release the lock on the file you are attempting the maintenance operation on, you will need to kill the appropriate process. An individual program or handle in the list provided by Process Explorer can be killed by selecting the process/handle/program entry and press delete to kill the process.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/the-case-of-the-mysterious-locked-file

Comment: Actually, in my case, it was BitDefender. It detected virus in the exe file each time I was  building the solution.