# .NET Core 3.1 Api Using NewtonsoftJson causes Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is my declaration for NewtonsoftJson in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo(culture);
});
```

I have added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package to my project already. However, when I try to run it, I get the exception below pointing to the code above. Am I supposed to load PresentationFramework as well? I don't recall needing to use it for my other Apis

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

EDIT:

I have updated the code below. However, the error still appears:

```
var culture = "en-US";
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture, false);
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
    });
```

EDIT 2:

I have commented out the AddNewtonSoftJson section and kept services.AddControllers. This is the part that is causing the exception.

EDIT 3:

This is how I load my appsettings.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    configuration = builder.Build();
```

This is the stacktrace:

> at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
> Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
> RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
> Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) at
> System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken
> caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule,
> MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean
> mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1&
> attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32
> decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean
> mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[T](Assembly element) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(Assembly assembly) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateDefaultParts(String entryAssemblyName) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersCore(IServiceCollection services) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllers(IServiceCollection services) at SDR_Filestore.Api.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\user1\source\repos\DotNetCore\appo_one\Fileserver.Api\Startup.cs:line 83 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.g__RunPipeline|0(IServiceCollection
> services) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object
> instance, IServiceCollection services) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection
> services) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.g__ConfigureServicesWithContainerConfiguration|0(IServiceCollection
> services) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
> services)

Comment: how are you setting value for culture ?

Comment: Does using `new CultureInfo(culture)` outside of the `.AddNewtonsoftJson` work?

Comment: I'm getting culture from my configuration. I have checked that theres a value there already.

Comment: How do I set culture outside?

Comment: How are you loading your configuration ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-5.0

Comment: btw try doing this see if it works, if the below works it will maybe point you to problem in loading config file : services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                    options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
                });

Comment: var culture = configuration["culture_title"];

Comment: The culture is a text like en-US

Comment: I updated my code to test but the error still appears for some reason.  I have removed options.SerializerSettings.Culture but the error appears also. I think its something to do with the entire section of services.AddControllers

Comment: How are you adding your appsettings.json file in configuration?

Comment: I have updated the question with the appsettings code

Comment: what is the value of hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath. Can you debug ? Alternatively try commenting the section as by default it will pick the appsettings in the root if you have    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) in your program.cs

Comment: It shows me the environment where appsettings is located "C:\\Users\\user1\\source\\repos\\dncore\\appo_one\\ST.Api"

Comment: I'm curious as to why PresentationFramework is being asked for

Comment: not sure I tried replicating your issue on a fresh project , i can't  :(. Do you get any stack trace what's tripping it ?

Comment: Some other package is trying to install NewtonSoft and its version clashes with the one you're trying to install

Comment: I see. I'll try to remove the microsoft one and see if I can run it

Comment: Actually, I discovered that it isn't newtonsoft. Its something t odo with services.addcontrollers

Comment: I posted the stacktrace as well.

Comment: Hang on **System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0** - it looks like a Full .Net reference. Can you run ProcessMonitor and tell us where VisualStudio is looking for that DLL?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I tried running processmonitor and starting my app but I am not sure what to look for in processmonitor?

Comment: I tried searching for the PresentationFramework in my existing references and I could find it as well.

Comment: I discovered what the issue was. One of my references packed a .Net Core 3.1 WPF app inside it as well. That caused PresentationFramework to be requested. Thank you for all your help so far everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hang on this error: **System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0**

It looks like a Full .Net reference, *not .net core*. PresentationFramework is WPF that came out with Full .Net 3.0 in 2008. Can you run [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and tell us where Visual Studio is looking for that DLL?

Quickly start a ProcessMonitor trace before you run the Visual Studio solution, then quickly stop ProcessMonitor tracing after Visual Studio throws the error. Then do a search in ProcessMonitor
for the DLL's name and see where it's being loaded from.

> You might discover the issue was one of your .Net Core 3.1 references packed a WPF app inside it as well. That caused PresentationFramework to be requested.

Ref, my own bounty answers:

- DLL Ref's and how to stop unknown Frameworks being referenced:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62948423/495455
- ProcessMonitor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664848/495455

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due to nuget package issue, try remove the packge and reintsall it